# Retrieve first row of csv using dictionary

Tags: python

I am reading a csv file using the csv.DictReader class.
I read on the python documentation that 
 class csv.DictReader(csvfile, fieldnames=None, restkey=None, restval=None, dialect='excel', *args, **kwds)

**If the fieldnames parameter is omitted, the values in the first row of the csvfile will be used as the fieldnames.**

I tried to get the first row of my csv file using the keys() method of dictionaries:

```
my_reader = csv.DictReader(src)
print(my_reader.keys())
```

Doing this, I get the following error:

```
    print(my_reader.keys())
    AttributeError: 'DictReader' object has no attribute 'keys'
```

Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fieldnames are stored in the attribute `fieldnames`:

```
my_reader = csv.DictReader(src)
print(my_reader.fieldnames)
```

`keys` is a dict method. `my_reader` is not a dict. However, it is an iterator that yields dicts, so you could also do this:

```
for row in my_reader:
    print(row.keys())
```